# Issues with Mirah

Tags: codenameone

I am using the Mirah library in Codename One mainly as an object mapper between Json and Java classes.

I am running into the issue where Mirah is trying to map classes that were not declared in the .mirah class. For example my .mirah class has a data mapper for Product

> data_mapper Product:ProductMapper

But the error is complaining about IUser interface and not the Product class! For a starter, I don't understand why Mirah would complain about a class that is not declared as a datamapper. Am I missing something ? Please keep in mind in my current code, Product has only primitive data type variables and absolutely no reference to the IUser interface or the User implementing class.

> nbproject\mirah-build-cn1.xml:152: 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find stub for interface IUser
>   at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler$2.visitClass(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:694)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:720)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:68)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:91)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scanAndReduce(TreeScanner.java:99)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.visitCompilationUnit(TreeScanner.java:120)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler$2.visitCompilationUnit(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:275)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:550)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:68)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:91)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compile(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:797)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileFile(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:174)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:211)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:214)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:214)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:214)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:214)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:193)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.WLMirahCompiler.compile(WLMirahCompiler.java:208)
>       at ca.weblite.mirah.ant.MirahcTask.execute(MirahcTask.java:158)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor68.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
>       at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 10 seconds)

I would also like to mention that I highly suspect that cleaning the project may not be cleaning all Mirah generated classes. Since I was unable to build my application at all due to the error above, I tried deleting the ".mirah" class from my project, then tried cleaning and rebuilding but I still received the same error from that point on.

The only way I was able to get the project to compile again is to start a brand new project and move my source file there leaving the .mirah class out.

I appreciate any insights!

More details **Updates below**

Hi Steve. Thank you very much for your feedback! I spent some time trying to track down the issue. I think the issue has to do somehow with Generics. As far as I know, generic types are substituted at compile time so I am guessing Codename One would support generics just fine. Also my code compiled well before attempting to go the Mirah route. I really think Mirah is a brilliant idea.

Here's few steps to recreate the issue. I started a CN1 Hello world project and created the following classes

1)IHouse

```
import java.util.List;

public interface IHouse<W extends IWindow> {

public int getHouseColor();

public void setHouseColor(int color);

public List<W> getWindows(); 

public void setWindows(List<W> windows);

}
```

2)IWindow

```
public interface IWindow {

public int getWindowColor();

public void setWindowColor(int newColor);

public String getShape();
}
```

3) RoundWindow

```
public class RoundWindow implements IWindow {

private int windowColor;
private String shape;

public RoundWindow() {
    String shape = "ROUND";
}

@Override
public int getWindowColor() {
    return windowColor;
}

@Override
public void setWindowColor(int newColor) {
    windowColor = newColor;
}

@Override
public String getShape() {
    return shape;
}

}
```

4) SquareWindow

```
public class SquareWindow implements IWindow {

private int windowColor;
private String shape;

public SquareWindow() {
    String shape = "SQUARE";
}

@Override
public int getWindowColor() {
    return windowColor;
}

@Override
public void setWindowColor(int newColor) {
    windowColor = newColor;
}

@Override
public String getShape() {
    return shape;
}
}
```

5) House

```
public class House implements IHouse<RoundWindow> {

private int houseColor;

List<RoundWindow> windows;

@Override
public int getHouseColor() {
    return houseColor;
}

@Override
public void setHouseColor(int color) {
    houseColor = color;
}

@Override
public List<RoundWindow> getWindows() {
    return windows;
}

@Override
public void setWindows(List<RoundWindow> windows) {
    this.windows = windows;
}

}
```

To Recap , I have a IHouse interface supporting any type of window that implements IWindow. Then the House class that implements the IHouse interface can strictly specify which Window it supports / works with.

This code compiles well in CN1 before adding the Mirah plugin.  Though I receive an identical error to what I had explained before when I add Mirah.

> the following error occurred while executing this line:
>   C:\Users\location\NetBeansProjects\Test\nbproject\mirah-build.xml:51: 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find stub for interface IHouse
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler$2.visitClass(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:694)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(JCTree.java:720)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:68)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:91)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scanAndReduce(TreeScanner.java:99)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.visitCompilationUnit(TreeScanner.java:120)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler$2.visitCompilationUnit(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:275)
>       at com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(JCTree.java:550)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreePathScanner.scan(TreePathScanner.java:68)
>       at com.sun.source.util.TreeScanner.scan(TreeScanner.java:91)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compile(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:797)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileFile(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:174)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:211)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:214)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:214)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:214)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:214)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler.compileDirectory(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:193)
>       at ca.weblite.asm.WLMirahCompiler.compile(WLMirahCompiler.java:208)
>       at ca.weblite.mirah.ant.MirahcTask.execute(MirahcTask.java:158)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor323.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor323.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.java:396)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
>       at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor323.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:286)
>       at org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:555)
>       at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)

Few Observation, if I remove the House class, the code builds well (showing "build successful" at the end) but I see the following warnings. I believe these are due to an attempt to pre-compile a generic interface where we don't know yet the exact type for w (until runtime).  This could be the root cause for the issue.

```
Failed to get signature for method 
public List<W> getWindows();
Failed to get signature for method 
public void setWindows(List<W> windows);
```

Finally,  changing my model design and getting rid of the Generics altogether gets my code to compile again without any Mirah complaint.   In my real project, I would like to keep my current design (with generics) for many reasons.

Would it be possible to also use the Mirah Json to Java conversion tool along with generics?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: Generics should work.  If you can send me the class that it is choking on (the one with `public List<W> getWindows()`, I'll add it to my test suite and try to hunt down the issue).

Comment: Yep Sorry! I posted the House class twice. I meant to really pose IHouse and then the implementing House class. I updated # 1) above the  IHouse interface

Comment: Actually,  Those warnings should still be fine.  The problem is the IUser interface.  Whatever is causing it to fail is centered around the IUser interface.  Relevant classes will be ones that either implement IUser, or reference it in its public method or field signatures  (i.e. parameters and return types).

Comment: So are you seeing the same issue with the 5 classes in the project where the build fails because of this error? 
"Could not find stub for interface IUser at ca.weblite.asm.JavaExtendedStubCompiler$2.visitClass(JavaExtendedStubCompiler.java:694)"
it's basically halting the build because of this issue.

Comment: No, I'm not seeing that issue.

Comment: Weird! As soon as I remove generics from my project, everything works well. The Mirah generated mappers are generated and usable. But as soon as I add the Generic parameters to IHouse<W extends IWindow>, it breaks and the project would no longer compile!  I can share both projects if you are curious (the one that works and the one that doesn't). I may fiddle with it for a bit. If I can't get it to work, I might take a different route for JSON / Java conversion. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

The Mirah netbeans plugin allows for two-way mirah-java dependencies in project.  To accomplish this, it first compiles "stubs" of the java sources in the project so that they can be referenced from Mirah during the mirah compile step.  After mirah is finished compiling to .classes, it then does the "real" java compilation step which references the compiled mirah files.  This is why it is referencing the IUser class.. that is the "pre-compile" step that is choking on it.

The error indicates that it can't find the IUser class while pre-compiling the java stubs.  I'd have to see the project to know why.

Comment: I updated the original question with more details! Sorry for the lengthy post. Also please let me know if you would need the whole project. I can zip it and send it. Thanks!